# Why is foreach loop outputting double sets of li tags?

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, foreach

Apologies for the noob question, but...

In wordpress 3.2.1, using wp-e-commerce:

I'm using the following code to output a field from an indexed array as an unordered list.

```
function tag_badges() {
  global $wpdb, $post;
  $tags = wp_get_product_tags($post->ID);
  foreach($tags as $key)
    // print_r ($key->name);
  echo "<li>$key->name<li/>";
}
```

This sort of works. But I'm getting an empty set of li tags for every tag that has a set.

e.g.

value1

value2

value3

When I output just the keys without markup, it just returns the three values that are in the array, e.g.

Key: Value1
Key: Value2
Key: Value3

so I'm fairly sure it's not because there are empty fields being output.

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: What does var_dump($tags) output?  Are there empty entries?

Comment: `print_r()` just prints nothing for null, so don't assume that only seeing three values printed means only three things are being operated on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just did a minor error in your output, you didn't close the `li` tag but added a new one:

```
echo "<li>$key->name<li/>";
#                      ^
```

To fix, move the `/` to the beginning of the second `li` tag to make it actually a closing tag:

```
echo "<li>$key->name</li>";
#                    ^
```

Comment: fer christ's sake. Thank you. Out of interest, do you think I should leave this question up or is it just too stupid to leave around?

Comment: Leave it around, it's a good example what can go wrong. It's not always that we do advanced errors all the time ;)

Comment: Haha I thought there was a 2nd `<li>` in the HTML, well spotted